# Screenshot of currently running application on IPhone

Tags: iphone, screenshot

On the IPhone, is it possible to get a screenshot of the currently running application, from another application that is running/backgrounded/being launched? or somehow make available a screenshot of the current application to another application that is then automatically launched?

Comment: I believe this is off topic but you can take a screenshot by holding the home key and pressing the lock/power button.  You may be able to simulate that.

Comment: This is on topic and a very good question.

Comment: Not officially. Xcode, however, does make screenshots somehow. See if you can tap into that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. It is not possible to know anything about another apps in iOS (if you're using documented methods).

Comment: Ok. What about having a local notification that triggers and checks for new screenshots on disk (taken by the user using the home+lock/power button combination) every few seconds using local notifications?

Comment: A different idea: I've heard that you're supposed to use the "applicationDidEnterBackground" method to clean up your GUI because the iphone takes a screenshot of your app which it then shows when you return to your app until it has loaded. Is this screenshot kept in memory or on disk? If on disk, perhaps it will be accessible from other apps?

Comment: Yes, those screen shots are save in photo library. You can access them using UIImagePickerController. I mean only screenshots made by power-home combination (not when applicationDidEnterBackground)

Comment: And as for notifications: the answer is no. You can't do that implicitly. The reason is simple: imagine the app that is able to access your photo library when you don't know and do whatever it want with photos (send somewhere etc.). So only UIImagePickerController...

Comment: Thanks. What about using the UIBackgroundModes key with the 'audio' value, having the background process output a silent audio stream and use UIImagePickerController to check for new images, then pop into the foreground if one is there?

Comment: It seems you don't completely understand: UIImagePickerController - is the view controller, so you can use it only manually (I mean only user can select images tapping on them manually). You don't have access to the image library (i.e. your doesn't know anything about it contents or any changes there).

Comment: So an IPhone app can't do something like "ls -lR" to list all files in a directory / in the filesystem, including the images in the image library?

Comment: Nope. It's very strict. Each application works only in it's own sandbox.

Comment: Actually I just managed to access the photos in the photo album using the ALAssetsLibrary.

Comment: Thanks for info! really didn't know. There are really huge amount of frameworks in iOS and you don't know all of them even after 2.5 years of programming for iOS devices :) But still, what is absolutely for sure: you can't have full access to the file system and other apps without jailbreaking the device.

Comment: Just a little remark: blocks as well as ALAssetsLibrary are available from iOS 4.0. So you should add additional checks for iOS version. if you don't - your app would crash on earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using Xcode's Organizer:

- in Xcode, select "Window" menu and then "Organizer"
- in the newOrganizer window, select "Devices"
- select your iPhone device and unfold
- select "Screenshots" at the bottom of the list
- now click on the "New screenshot" button (bottom right of the window)

You can export screenshots just by drag/drop on your desktop.